# How to extract a td from html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one variable its having some html data. I want to extract one `td` from that html.

If I give `alert(returnData)` its giving the following output.

```
<tr class='addedrow'>
    <td id="abc">DOM-001
        <input id="bill_details_1_narration" name="bill_details[1][narration]" type="hidden" />
    </td>
    <td>DOMSTAL O CAPSULES</td>
    <td>
        <select id="item_details_batch_number" name="item_details[batch_number]">
            <option value="47">BATCH-830</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="bill_details_quantity" name="bill_details[quantity]" size="2" type="text" value="2.0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="item_details_cost_price" name="item_details[cost_price]" size="2" type="text" value="23391.0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here I want to extract the value `1` from `bill_details_1_narration`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: rather than trying to the parse strin gof id, I woul duse data-aid, relying on the new html 5 data attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `returnData` is HTML node that should work:

```
var bill_details = $(`#bill_details_1_narration`,returnData).val();
```

But since you alert it I it's string, why is it so? How do you return that data?

**UPDATE:**

```
var valArray = [],
billDet = $('input[name$="[narration]"]', returnData);

billDet.each(function () {
    valArray.push($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: var i = 1; i < 3; i++ here we can't limit it to 3. it might be anything

Answer (score 2):

You can transfer value from one element to another like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_Expeditor').html($('#id_Receiver').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question refers to the `td` but from my understanding I believe you want to retrieve `1` from the `name` attribute since `1` does not appear anywhere else in your markup:

If you want to retrieve the value from:

```
bill_details[1][narration]
```

Firstly I'd suggest using `data-attributeName`

You could then use this code to extract `1` from the attribute.

```
var obj = $("#bill_details_1_narration");
var attr = obj.attr("name");
var sub = attr.substring(attr.indexOf('[') +1, attr.indexOf("]"));

alert(sub);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8uFC/

Comment: ("#bill_details_1_narration"); here the 1 will change. first time 1, second time 2,,,